# Subset Sum in python using DP

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic-programming, backtracking

I'm following this [link](https://www.ideserve.co.in/learn/subset-sum-dynamic-programming) to write a DP solution for Subset problem.

```
def subsetSum(input, target):
    row, col = len(input)+1, target+1
    db = [[False] * col] * row
    for i in range(row):
        db[i][0] = True

    for i in range(1, row):
        for j in range(1, col):
            db[i][j]=db[i-1][j]
            if db[i][j]==False and j>=input[i-1]:
                db[i][j] = db[i-1][j-input[i-1]]

    return db[i][j]

target = 5
input = [1,3,9,2]
subsetSum(input, target)
```

Interestingly after every iteration of "**j**", **db[i-1]** (the previous row where we are referring to the values) is also getting updated. I'm really lost whats happening here. Please suggest.

Please find this [link](https://repl.it/repls/MysteriousBestBaitware) for the printed statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in this line
`db = [[False] * col] * row`.
When you use the `*` operator, a copy of the original list is made that refers to the original list.

Consider the following example:

```
l = [[1]*5]*3
print(l) # prints [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
l[0][0] = 0
print(l) # prints [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Each inner list refers to the same object. Thus, when the first element of the first list is changed, all lists appear to change.

To remedy this, you can use a list comprehension:

```
l = [[1]*5 for _ in range(3)]
print(l) # prints [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
l[0][0] = 0
print(l) # prints [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Specifically, you can replace your assignment to `db` with the following:

`db = [[False]*col for _ in range(row)]`.